# Call jquery function in Wordpress correctly

Tags: jquery, wordpress

i'm developing a website through wordpress source code. I'm using a child theme for twenty ten, and i have a jquery file with a function that i want to incorporate in the website. My problem is: how can i call this file through "functions.php" and not by pasting the script on the html page?

I found i should use something like this:

```
         function my_scripts() {
         wp_enqueue_script( 'my-sweet-script', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/script.js', array('jquery') );
     }

 add_action('template_redirect', 'my_scripts');
```

And where should i put the .js file so that he doesn't get replaced with wordpress updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upload js file in your template directory.. 
something like /wp-content/themes/my-theme/
or /wp-content/themes/my-theme/js/

> get_bloginfo('template_directory')

this will return you the directory path of your template

> wp_enqueue_script( 'my-sweet-script',
>   get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/script.js', array('jquery') );

this is the safe and recommended method of adding JavaScript to a WordPress generated page

> function my_scripts() {
>            wp_enqueue_script( 'my-sweet-script', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/script.js', array('jquery') );
>        }
>
> add_action('template_redirect', 'my_scripts');

this code should be added to function.php that should be found in your child theme (path ike: /wp-content/themes/my-theme/functions.php)

Comment: but the var 'template_directory' will return the path of my main theme and not the child right?
in that case, if i put there the js file, with an wordpress update the file may disappear correct?

Comment: Solved with some more searchs. Thanks!